# Does windows DFS (DFSR) resume a partial transfer if a WAN link is lost?

Tags: replication, dfs, dfs-r

*Q: Does windows DFS (DFSR) resume a partial transfer if a WAN link is lost?*

This seems like an obvious "yes" but, hoping someone here can provide a definitive answer.

**Background**

The environment consists of two geographically separate networks connected by a site to site VPN.  Location A has a DSL internet connection.  Location B has a T1.  We have had issue with replication using other technologies previously as Location A experiences some network issues resulting in packet loss.  Therefore, we need a technology that supports resuming replication to overcome external causes of failure.

**Research Trail**

To this point, the resources I have found that most closely match my question are:

1. When a replication schedule closes while a file is being replicated, it is paused and replication continues where it paused when the schedule opens. (http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc773238(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_080)
2. When a WAN link fails during replication DFSR will continue attempting to replicate while the schedule remains open.  (http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc773238(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_017)

However, I am unable to find a direct answer to my question which can be rephrased as "When a WAN link fails during replication will DSFR continue replicating where it left off or will it restart?"

Some files that will be replicated may be in excess of 1GB, therefore, I'm trying to ensure DFSR has some form of handling resuming of partially replicated files (think --partial flag for rsync).